Rust vector's `get_unchecked` still performs bounds checking?
Learning rust and tried running this code (https://godbolt.org/z/b6Yrj3dfx):
fn main() {
    let foo = vec![1,2,3];

    println!("Value: {}", unsafe { foo.get_unchecked(3) });
}

Output:
thread 'main' panicked at core/src/panicking.rs:221:5:
unsafe precondition(s) violated: slice::get_unchecked requires that the index is within the slice
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
thread caused non-unwinding panic. aborting.
Program terminated with signal: SIGSEGV

I was expecting the program to print out some random value just like in C/C++, but from the error message it seems that it's still doing bounds checking?
Documentation of get_unchecked:

Returns a reference to an element or subslice, without doing bounds checking.

What gives?

Note that even in C dereferencing a pointer past the end of the array is undefined behavior. So you're not guaranteed to "get a random value", even if that's what often happens in practice.

By using unsafe, you promised to not call get_unchecked() with an out of bounds index. You broke this promise. You invoked Undefined Behavior. Now Rust is free to do whatever it wants - and that includes panicking (in fact, a deterministic panic is probably the best outcome you can expect in this scenario). This is why Rust is allowed to do what it does.
As for why it does what it do, the reason is to have a safety net. In debug builds, Rust will make extra assertions to help you detect UB in your code. In release mode, this will be disabled, so the code can be the most performant possible.

Note that in this case, even release mode fails with an "Illegal instruction" (playground) rather than returning some random value. That's because the compiler is able to see at compile time that the index would always be out of bound and emits an ud2 instruction instead of attempting to read.

Note that the relevant code snippet for this question can be found here. From the documentation of assert_unsafe_precondition: "The check is enabled at runtime if debug assertions are enabled when the caller is monomorphized. In const-eval/Miri checks implemented with this macro for language UB are always ignored."

@Jmb seems a bit unusual that the compiler would do this though. For many other memory safety bugs, if detected at compile time, compilation would just fail and output one of its many helpful error messages. But here it chose to crash the program at runtime?
